# Код ответа 204 приводит к ошибке

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker, rest

Все запросы со статусом ответа 204 завершаются ошибкой. Без кода ответа и других заголовков

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id): Response
{
    $user = $this->repository->find($id);
    $this->repository->update(
        $user,
        $request->only(['name','email','password','isActive'])
    );
    $this->repository->save($user);

    return response()->noContent(204);
}
```

[image: FireFox console]

Любые варианты ответов с кодом 204 заканчиваться одинаково.
Приложение запущено из докера, где nginx, fpm и фронт (vue) находятся в отдельных контейнерах.

Конфиг nginx:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /dev/stderr warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events { worker_connections  1024; }
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /dev/stdout  main;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    gzip  on;
    server {
        listen 80;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
        root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        charset utf-8;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        error_page 404 /index.php;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass clicka:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "попадают в catch", и где находится этот "catch"? Также исправь вопрос и вставь в него код __текстом__, а не картинками.

Comment: И при чём тут nginx и PHP есть у вас явно JS падает

Comment: Нет, падает не JS, там вообще нечему падать, только запрос и все. Кстати в Postman та же картина. PHP скорее всего тоже не при чем. Тут либо nginx либо docker

Comment: А что именно шлёт PATCH запрос, и как обрабатывает ответ?

Comment: PATCH шлет json, что в нем абсолютно не важно, сервер данные получает и успешно сохраняет в БД. Если не ставить код ответа 204, то прилетает корректный ответ со статусом 200 и все прекрасно работает.
Никак не обрабатывает. В этом суть статуса 204 - выполнено успешно, ничего делать не надо!

Comment: Проблема проявляется только когда фронт в watch моде. Если сбилдить, то все хорошо. То есть возможно тут что-то с CORS

Comment: Так же не важно PATCH, POST, PUT или GET. Результат одинаковый

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему путем отказа от Докера